# What sort of ewok questions are allowed on SuperUser?

Tags: discussion

I thought SuperUser was intended to be very generalised, where almost anything goes. From the blog:

> If your question has to do with computers, it will be allowed there.
>
> But then again, so are Ewoks. Be careful what you ask for, I guess.

But, after noticing a lot of questions being closed, I checked the FAQ and saw that it limited to computer hardware and software, excluding games.

There's [one ewok question](https://superuser.com/questions/2822/what-do-you-do-next-in-life-after-starring-in-star-wars-as-an-ewok-closed), but it was closed for not being computer related.

So, what's up with that? Are Ewoks allowed or not?

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to go out on a Endor limb, and say: no, not really. Unless it somehow involves a laptop, which is just disturbing.

However, if you are having problems with your 'droids...

Comment: Yub yub      ^_^

Answer (score 3):

I do suppose that "I'm an ewok, and i'm having trouble with my mouse and keyboard, what can i do" might count as a niche hardware question...

Comment: "Hi Ewok..."

At the weekly EwAnon meetings.